# Textviews overlapping in Listview

Tags: android

Hi I have made a custom listview where each row in the row item layout has three textviews. I am fetching data from the server and displaying in the listview. When there is a large chunk of text in the first textview, the first textview starts overlapping the other two textviews. I want all the textviews in one line. How do I do this?

This is my listview row item layout:

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ingredientName"
        style="@style/MyTextFont"

        android:lines="3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:ellipsize="none"
        android:scrollHorizontally="false"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        style="@style/MyTextFont"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"

        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/measureTv"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.94"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ingredientName"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/measureTv"
        style="@style/MyTextFont"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` in place of `ConstraintLayout` with `layout_weight`.

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="8dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/ingredientName"
                style="@style/MyTextFont"
                android:lines="3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:ellipsize="none"
                android:scrollHorizontally="false"
                android:layout_weight:"1"

 />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/quantity"
                style="@style/MyTextFont"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"

                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_weight:"1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/measureTv"
                style="@style/MyTextFont"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:layout_weight:"1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: using linear layout as compared to constraint layout is easy.. No , i don't think so that it can be done with constraint layout

Comment: I guess it cant be done with constraint layout. With linear layour it works fine.

Comment: It can be done with constraintLayout as well, check my answer

Answer (score 1):

You should use these below attributes in your TextView tag.

```
android:maxLines="1"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

Or

> In Case you want to scroll the Text from right to left in the same
>   `TextView` (to see complete Text), try using this below code :-
>
> ```
>  android:ellipsize="marquee"
> ```

Comment: why `ellipsize` is required? what does it do?

Comment: at the end: this is how it would... look, basically, it will add `...` at the end to stand in for the omitted bits.

Comment: agree , make sense @JayPatel

Comment: It gives the same result unfortunately.

Comment: what is your "MyTextFont" style?

Comment: ellipsize wont work here, his textview will is wrap_content and will take full width if required, ellipsize only works with views that are constrained or have fixed width. Check my answer for more info

Answer (score 0):

When using constrainLayouts, make sure you give width or height as 0dp if you are making constraints on both the sides.

In your case the textview is wrap content and it will overlap other textviews no matter what, simply change it to 0dp and it will work perfectly.

Making constraint will lead to multiple lines text, if you dont want that define the maxLines in the textview and use ellipse end as well

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="8dp">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ingredientName"

    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="28dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:lines="3"
    android:scrollHorizontally="false"
    android:text="TextVidasdsdadadsadadasdaew"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/quantity"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quantity"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="2dp"

    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/measureTv"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/ingredientName"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/measureTv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="TextViedssadadasdasdasdasdasdw"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/quantity"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Comment: Still overlaps:(

Comment: can you post a screenshot of what you are trying to achieve vs what you are getting. I have updated my code for putting them all in a row equally space